# Failing to display modal content in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following file

```
_result.html.erb
_show.html.erb
_show.js.erb
```

I put a button in _result partial that should open the _show partial in a modal. but when the user click on the link, it only shows a bar, not containt. Am i missing part of the procedure please? it seems fairly easy in the  tutorials that I found.
My code is as follows:

**_show.html.erb**

```
<div id="modal-window" class="modal hide fade" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
  <h3 class="section_title">
Hello this is the Show modal
  </h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**_result.html.erb** (which is located in Welcome.html.erb)

```
<div id="modal-window" class="modal hide fade" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**show.js.erb**

```
$("#modal-window").find(".modal-content").html("<%= j (render 'invitations/show') %>");
$("#modal-window").modal('show');
```

All I get for now is a line:

[image: filed rendering of modal]

does anybody know why the contain is  not showing, although I literally used the same tagging and id label [Kolosek - Creating modal in rails](https://qiita.com/Kolosek/items/4ee80eb0c6dd0af4b1b7)
The controller:

```
  def show
    @invitation = Invitation.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.js {render :layout => false}
    end
  end
```

Comment: When i launch the page and inspect the code, i can actually see the modal and its tags, with the text Hello this is the Show modal, but for some reason it does not render on the actual page.

Comment: You are trying to open a modal inside another another. That's probably not possible.

Comment: Hi @Pavan, inside another modal you mean ? Can you elaborate please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see that you are following [*this*](https://qiita.com/Kolosek/items/4ee80eb0c6dd0af4b1b7) tutorial to create a modal, but your code isn't correct! You are trying to **display a modal inside another modal** instead you should display its contents inside the modal. Modify your `_show.html.erb` to below

```
#_show.html.erb
<div class="modal-header">
  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">x</button>
  <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
  *Modal content comes here*
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
  <button class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
</div>
```